# My Html file is not showing any style

Tags: css, stylesheet

I was starting a simple static HTML website, but I realized that, for some reason, it doesn't show any css style. At first I though it was a linking problem, but then I realized that the style attribute was not working even in the HTML file. Here's a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <p style="text-decoration: underlined;">This is my body green</p>
    <p>This is my body </p>
    <p>This is my body </p>
    <p>This is my body </p>
    <p>This is my body </p>
    <p>This is my body </p>
    <p>This is my body </p>
    <p>This is my body </p>
    <p>This is my body </p>
    <p>This is my body </p>
</body>
```

And the stylesheet:

```
body {
    background: #c9c9c9;

}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your mark-up here is invalid - you're missing the root `<html>` tag.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you! Would you be so kind as to mark my answer as correct?

Comment: It's supposed to be marked as correct now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `<p style="text-decoration: underlined;">This is my body green</p>`

You need `<p style="text-decoration: underline;">This is my body green</p>`

It's `underline` not `underlined`.

That will solve your inline CSS problem, after you follow Tieson T.'s advice and use the proper HTML markup.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. The problem is, i still can't figure out why the style.css doesn't link correctly. When I link it via the <link> tag, the only thing that changes is the background to grey, no other style is applied.

Comment: Well if the background color changes to grey that presumably means you're linked up correctly... so, can you post the full contents of your CSS file?

Comment: Confirm that the link is intact by changing `#c9c9c9;` to `pink;` and let me know if your background changes to pink

Comment: Here it is:

body {
    background: #c9c9c9;

}

p { 

 font-size: 50px;
 color: red;
}

Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: Oh, and the grey color was not the c9c9c9, it was darker. By the way, the pink color didn't work either.

Comment: Where is `style.css` located in relation to your html file? In the same directory?

Comment: Yep, they're both in the same folder. It seems to be linked correctly, because when i change the link to an unexistent stylesheet file just to see what happens, the background changes to white. Hmm, I guess i'll go get some fresh air so I can figure out what is going on. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Change `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` because your current declaration is telling the browser to look for `style.css` in a *different* directory, one level up.

Comment: That was the problem. how could I not see it! I guess I'm not good at mondays. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You try this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css"> --->MAKE SURE OF DESIRED    PATH
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p style="text-decoration: underline;">This is my body green</p>
<p>This is my body </p>
<p>This is my body </p>
<p>This is my body </p>
<p>This is my body </p>
<p>This is my body </p>
<p>This is my body </p>
<p>This is my body </p>
<p>This is my body </p>
<p>This is my body </p>
</body>
</html> ---->Close HTML TAG
```